# adding mandrill email attachments using foreach loop

Tags: php, email, email-attachments, mandrill

I need to reply to incoming emails including the attachment they contain.
I wrote this code, but for some reason when I check my debug log and mandrill API logs the attachment isn't included into the request.
Where's my fault?

```
if ($message['attachments']) 
    {

        $mail= 
            [
                'html' => $mail->msg->html,
                'text' => $mail->msg->text,
                'subject' => $mail->msg->subject,
                'from_email' => 'test@test.com',
                'from_name' => $mail->msg->from_name,
                'to' => [
                    [
                        'email' => 'test@test.com',
                        'name' => 'test@test.com',
                        'type' => 'to'
                    ]
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    'Reply-To' => $mail->msg->from_email
                ],
            ];
            //just some sample data for testing
            foreach ($message['attachment'] as $attachment) 
                {
                    $mail['attachments']['name'] ='sample.png';
                    $mail['attachments']['type'] ='image/png';
                    $mail['attachments']['content'] ='iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDrEX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
                }

                $async = false;
                $ip_pool = 'Main Pool';

                $v = var_export( $mail, true);
                file_put_contents('phplog.txt', 'gesendet: ' . $v, FILE_APPEND);

                $result = $mandrill->messages->send($mail, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Below line looks suspicious. If you check https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html  here. You can clearly see `attachments` is a multidimensional array.

```
 //just some sample data for testing
        foreach ($message['attachment'] as $attachment) 
            {
                $mail['attachments']['name'] ='sample.png';
                $mail['attachments']['type'] ='image/png';
                $mail['attachments']['content'] ='iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDrEX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
            }
```

At least it should be like following, but still you don't use `$attachment` in your code. But the correct usage like following.

```
    foreach ($message['attachment'] as $key => $attachment) 
        {
            $mail['attachments'][$key]['name'] ='sample.png';
            $mail['attachments'][$key]['type'] ='image/png';
            $mail['attachments'][$key]['content'] ='iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDrEX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
        }
```

If you want to try in more clear way please use as following :

```
$attachment = [];
$attachment['name'] ='sample.png';
$attachment['type'] ='image/png';
$attachment['content'] ='iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDrEX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';




$mail['attachments'][] = $attachment;
```

**UPDATED ACCORDING TO COMMENT :**

things look fine, just change your if statement  `if ($message['attachments'])` to `if (is_array($message['attachments']) && count($message['attachments']) > 1)`  then after if statment place `$message['attachments'] = array_values($message['attachments']);`

so loop like the following one. Just pay attention to `$attachment` I added to semantic keys to it, you can change according to your needs. I don't know where is your source you getting file, static or file upload etc. I added as an example.

```
    foreach ($message['attachment'] as $key => $attachment) 
        {
            $mail['attachments'][$key]['name'] =$attachment['fileName'];
            $mail['attachments'][$key]['type'] =$attachment['mimeType'];
            $mail['attachments'][$key]['content'] = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($attachment['filePath']))); ;
        }
```

Comment: What's the best way to use your code into my loop (to loop thourgh each incoming attachment and attach it to the new mail I like to send)?